# How to route sgtl5000 audio within the chip?

Tags: embedded, alsa, alsamixer

I have an embedded device with an sgtl5000 audio codec, linked to an iMX8 CPU via SPI.

According to the datasheet, there is a direct route from LINE_IN to HP_OUT, which avoids sound travelling through the SPI connection to the CPU.  [image: datasheet block diagram]

Does ALSA/alsamixer allow me to do this routing, or is it restricted to only those audio flows which traverse the kernel?

---

Using `amixer`, I can see:

```
root@test217:~# amixer 
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 127
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 89 [70%] [-7.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 89 [70%] [-7.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'DAC' 'LINE_IN'
  Item0: 'DAC'
...
```

What command lets me switch `Headphone Mux`>>`Item0` from `DAC` to `LINE_IN`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like part of of achieving what I need (manipulation of the two Muxes) can be done with the amixer command itself:

```
root@test217:~# amixer sset 'Headphone Mux' 'LINE_IN'
Simple mixer control 'Headphone Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'DAC' 'LINE_IN'
  Item0: 'LINE_IN'
root@test217:~# amixer sset 'Capture Mux' 'MIC_IN'
Simple mixer control 'Capture Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'MIC_IN' 'LINE_IN'
  Item0: 'MIC_IN'
```

This is not yet checked, as I do not have access to a speaker.